# Nginx - Redirect index.php to root, but not if index.php exists in folders

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've tried all kind of things to make this work and I can't find it that's why I'm requesting some help.

Basically, I want to:

/index.php -> / (Easy to do)
But without affecting:
/folder1/index.php

So far all my attempts redirected /folder1/index.php to /

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use try_files directive. Basically try to use the file and if it does not exists go to a specified (maybe internally) location block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inside server block like this

```
server {
    if ($request_uri = "/index.php") {
        return 301 https://yourdomain.com;
    }
}
```